# When to use “lieu” or “endroit” ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, indications-de-lieu

Can both *lieu* and *endroit* (words for *place*) be used interchangeably?

- In the scenario of deciding a venue for a party/picnic?
- If the place has already been decided but one needs to convey it to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I see it, *lieu* tends to be

- A vaster or vaguer place than *endroit* :

  > On s'était donné rendez-vous là, à cet endroit exact *(correct)*

  vs

  > On s'était donné rendez-vous là, dans ce lieu exact *(sounds awkward)*

  You'd never say for instance

  > Sa chemise était trouée en plusieurs lieux *(precise spot on a piece of clothing)*
- Slightly more formal, old-fashioned than *endroit* and/or describing an official/ceremonious place

  > Avez-vous choisi le lieu ? *(formal/written)*

  vs

  > Vous avez choisi l'endroit ? *(everyday/spoken)*

  Also

  > Le lieu de l'enterrement *(correct)*

  vs

  > L'endroit de l'enterrement *(awkward, could sound inappropriate)*

You could get away only learning the idiomatic expressions containing *lieu*

> Lieu de rendez-vous
>
> Lieu du drame
>
> Lieu de mémoire
>
> Lieu de culte
>
> Arriver sur les lieux
>
> etc.

and using *endroit* for everything else.

Sure, there are tons of these expressions in French but if it's just about deciding for a party/picnic place, you probably won't need them — just say *endroit*.

Comment: +1, this answer quite sums it up. We say "sa chemise était trouée par endroits". "Lieu" is also the usual and legal word for a house, a building, a public place ("lieu public")

Comment: « L'endroit de l'enterrement », comment s'avère-t-elle déplacée ?

Comment: @LePressentiment Si on s'adresse à la famille d'un défunt par exemple. Quand des termes un peu solennels sont attendus, "endroit" me parait bizarre, en tout cas c'est mon ressenti. Et encore plus à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "lieu" is slightly more precise and "endroit" imprecise.
As for many expressions that had been demonstrated above, using "lieu" implies that the person(s) we talk/write to already have a hint/knowledge of the place.
("le lieu de l'enterrement").

On the other hand, "endroit" has a more vague feeling.